# Datatable scroll option is not working when using an external javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I use datatables in my web project and I want to open scrollbar. I used this code and it worked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dataTableStoreCapacity').DataTable( {
        "scrollX": true
    });
});
```

But there are many pages in project that use datatables and I want them all to have scrollbar. I have added scrollbar to a global js. file which is already used in these pages and working without any problem but nothing changed. I have very little knowledge on jquery and I could not find the solution on my own. is there any suggestions how should I approach to this problem or is there something I miss? Here is the updated code that doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    globalKWP.dataTableInstance('dataTable', [{ extend: 'copy' }]);
});
```

this is my global .js file

```
var globalKWP = {
    language: '',
    dataTableInstance: function (tableName, headbuttonArr, lengthMenuArr) {
        var btnArray = [];
        var languageUrl = '';
        if (lengthMenuArr == undefined) {
            lengthMenuArr = [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "Tümü"]];
            var item = { extend: 'pageLength' };
            btnArray.push(item);
        }
        if (headbuttonArr == undefined) {
            headbuttonArr = [{ extend: 'copy' }, { extend: 'pdf', title: tableName }, { extend: 'excel', title: tableName }, { extend: 'print' }];
        }
        for (var btn in headbuttonArr) {
            btnArray.push(headbuttonArr[btn]);
        }
        if (globalKWP.language == 'tr') {
            languageUrl = '/Scripts/Other/datatable/tr.txt';
        }
        var dataTable = $('#' + tableName).DataTable({
            "dom": 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: btnArray,
            "lengthMenu": lengthMenuArr,
            "language": { "url": languageUrl },
            "scrollX": true
        });
        return dataTable;
    },
    dataTableInstanceWithOptions: function (tableName, options) {
        if (globalKWP.language == 'tr') {
            languageUrl = '/Scripts/Other/datatable/tr.txt';
            options["language"] = { "url": languageUrl };
        }
        var dataTable = $('#' + tableName).DataTable(options);
        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is difference in the global variable what you have in the file `globalKWP` and what you have used  `globalJS`. Is that a typo error? Also do you see any errors in console ?

Comment: i was going to edit filename so thats why i changed it sorry for my mistake and problem is not that. edit: there is no error in chrome console.

Comment: It may be an iteration issue.  Cache all the tables that you want in a variable (do this by giving them all the same classes).  Then iterate through them with the function that you have above.

Comment: @onurdemir clear your browser cache and try once..